# writing and installing your own leiningen plugin

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have been able to run a custom plugin from within my projects project.clj, and even leiningen/plugin.clj (ie just a private plugin) - but when I go to put this plugin in its own project - I am unable to get it to work at all.

Following the advice, I should create a new project, and have a namespace of leiningen.myplugin etc etc... but the jar that I produce doesn't seem to provide the new task in the project (either via jar, or via clojars).

http://nakkaya.com/2010/02/25/writing-leiningen-plugins-101/
https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PLUGINS.md

Anyone who has published a plugin care to confirm if the above is correct - or is there some crucial step I am missing? (I assume my task goes in core.clj in the plugin project)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `:eval-in-leiningen` option set to true in the project.clj?

In addition if you want to use the task all around with your leiningen without having to add it to the dev dependencies of the project where you need to use it you need to use `lein plugin install`

Or did i miss something about your problem

Comment: yeah - I thought it would be something like that - but I have that. I need to deep dive into some other plugins to work out what I am missing. This plugin is only for use in the context of an application - so the plugin install is for system wide use - right?

Comment: yes plugin install is for system wide use. For use in single applivcation it should be enough that it is the class path and you have the :eval-in-leiningen set to true in your application (the one using the plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `eval-in-leiningen` doesn't need to be used for very simple project-specific plugins or tasks, and it can sometimes wreak build havoc.  You can enable a Leiningen task for a given project by just using `.lein-classpath` for that project.  More information here:

[Project-level Leiningen Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240439/project-level-leiningen-plugin/12310931#12310931)