# Project-level Leiningen Plugin

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In Leiningen versions 1.x.x I was able to define a `lein foo` task valid only in a single project by putting the following in that project's `project.clj`:

```
(defproject tester "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]])

;; Create a task, "foo"

(ns leiningen.foo
  (:require (leiningen [uberjar :as uberjar])))

(defn foo [project & args]
  (println "Do something here first, then make the uberjar.")
  (uberjar/uberjar project))
```

You can get a little more information about this here:

http://nakkaya.com/2010/02/25/writing-leiningen-plugins-101/

In 2.x.x, I'm not able to do this anymore (i.e., I get `'foo' is not a task.`  It seems way, way overkill for me to have to start a separate project for this task.  **Is it still possible to define a task within project.clj for leiningen 2.x.x?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "no", but it is still fairly easy to define a project level task:  Add `:eval-in-leiningen true` to your `defproject` definition and move the task definition to `src/leiningen/foo.clj`.

Comment: Sorry, no dice.  I found that tip, too, and it doesn't seem to do anything in this case.  I've update my question with a complete `project.clj` to complete the example.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I didn't realized that you had your "foo" definition inside your project.clj file. Updated my answer with the correct response (hopefully)

Comment: That did it!  It's a little more of a pain, but still not too bad.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S. - I also edited the answer to to something I would find a little more clear if I was reading.  Hope you don't mind and thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using `.lein-classpath` to point to a directory outside of `src` containing the tasks.  For example, if you have the plugin in `src/leiningen/foo.clj`, you can do, at the project root:

```
$ mkdir tasks
$ mv src/leiningen tasks/
$ echo tasks > .lein-classpath
```

The reason you might want to avoid `:eval-in-leiningen true` is that it has some funny behaviors when you're trying to do AOT compilation for a `main` class.  Specifically, you get:

```
Compilation failed: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory, compiling:(testproj/core.clj:1)
```

When trying to compile/run a even a simple test example.  More information at:

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/769

Comment: How do you specify libraries/deps required by your task?